# Static functions inlining in Java

Tags: java, optimization, inlining

**First code**:

```
public static int pitagoras(int a, int b)
{
    return (int) Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);
}

public static int distance(int x, int y, int x2, int y2)
{
    return pitagoras(x - x2, y - y2);
}
```

`distance` is called very often. When I compiled it with `javac` and then decompiled with `javap -c` I got this bytecode:

```
public static int pitagoras(int, int);
  Code:
   0:   iload_0
   1:   iload_0
   2:   imul
   3:   iload_1
   4:   iload_1
   5:   imul
   6:   iadd
   7:   i2d
   8:   invokestatic    #24; //Method java/lang/Math.sqrt:(D)D
   11:  d2i
   12:  ireturn

public static int distance(int, int, int, int);
  Code:
   0:   iload_0
   1:   iload_2
   2:   isub
   3:   iload_1
   4:   iload_3
   5:   isub
   6:   invokestatic    #34; //Method pitagoras:(II)I
   9:   ireturn
```

It seems that `javac` hasn't optimized second function, `distance`.

**Second code**, I think, faster:

```
public static int distance(int x, int y, int x2, int y2)
{
    return (int) Math.sqrt((x - x2) * (x - x2) + (y - y2) * (y - y2));
}
```

And its bytecode:

```
public static int distance(int, int, int, int);
  Code:
   0:   iload_0
   1:   iload_2
   2:   isub
   3:   iload_0
   4:   iload_2
   5:   isub
   6:   imul
   7:   iload_1
   8:   iload_3
   9:   isub
   10:  iload_1
   11:  iload_3
   12:  isub
   13:  imul
   14:  iadd
   15:  i2d
   16:  invokestatic    #24; //Method java/lang/Math.sqrt:(D)D
   19:  d2i
   20:  ireturn
```

Is `invokestatic` so fast that it's the same as inlining static function? Why `javac` did not optimize this? Or maybe it is in fact optimized and these two codes will give the same, but I'm missing something?

Comment: Offtopic: The guy is named `Pythagoras` and not `Pitagoras`...

Comment: Maybe it will be done by the JIT at runtime ...

Comment: @brimborium it looks like in spanish it is written with 'i' and not a 'y': http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pit%C3%A1goras

Comment: @GuillaumePolet That's quite interesting (and very irritating). Pythagoras is a greek name, so I think it should be spelled greek.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`javac` doesn't optimise. That's the job of the JVM implementation (typically HotSpot).

There used to be a few optimisations in `javac` but they complicated the code and allegedly tended to arrange the code so that HotSpot optimisations were inhibited.

HotSpot optimisations are generally done dynamically after thousands of iterations (configurable, default dependent upon whether using "Client", "Server" or tiered versions).

There are some things that `javac` is required to do by the language specification, such as inlining constants and combining literal strings.

Answer (score 4):

The Java language does not define inlined functions. Many (perhaps most) Just-In-Time (JIT) compilers will dynamically (at run time) replace such static function calls with inlined code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that performance of both version will be similar because JVM uses JIT to increase the performance.

Answer (score 1):

The kind of optimization you're looking for (inlining) doesn't necessarily occur at compile time, but it's quite possible that the Just in Time (JIT) compiler will perform it during runtime.

So it's unlikely that you'll be able to see the inlining happen at the byte code level, more likely, it'll occur at the native code level during program execution.

Answer (score 1):

The given answers are right : javac does not inline methods as it may not be the best thing to do.

Suppose that the `distance()` method is called once in a while but not very often. Optimizing it by inlining `pitagoras()` and stuff would slow down compilation for something that is barely used.

On the other hand, Hotspot knows when a method is called and how many times it is called. If the method is executed often, then Hotspot may inline it and compile it to native code, but only if it improves performances. Remember that Hotspot is the only component that **knows** if an optimization is a good thing or not.

Also, note that javac may do one optimization : it eliminates dead code. Consider this class :

```
public class Test {
public final static boolean ENABLED=false;

public static void main(String... args) { 
  if(ENABLED)
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

The compiled bytecode for the main method is this :

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   return
```

=> javac detected that the `println` line could not be reached and removed it.